# locking a object using hiberante session.load

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, locking

Hibernate has PESSIMISTIC locking mechanism that can be used to lock a db row.

session.lock(Object object, LockMode lockMode) .

Lets say i lock a object :

```
1)session.lock(myObject.LockMODE.READ)
2)session.lock(myObject,LockMODE.UPGRADE)
3)session.lock(myObject.LockMODE.UPGRADE_NOWAIT)
```

1. If some other thread also issues the above statments 1, what
   will happend to it? Will that thread simply block?OR will it get
   some kind of exception?Something like CannotAcquireLock exception? I
   would like to understand the behavior for 1,2,3 .
2. If a thread acquires a lock and then dies what happens?Is the
   lock released automatically?Or is the record locked forever?

   ```
     session.lock(myObject,LOCKMODE.SOME_LOCK_MODE)
     //thread dies . (lets say JVM is killed)
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lock is bound to the transaction. It is released once the transaction is committed or rolled back. If your thread dies and keeps your transaction dangling, the lock still holds.

Other threads trying to obtain the lock will simply wait.

If I remember correctly, the call to lock() results in a `select ... for update` SQL statement.

Comment: Thanks for answering. How do i make my other thread not to wait? I want the other threads to return(may be with some exception) if they cant acquire lock.

Comment: I'm not sure that it is possible. I just checked our code where we use the lock(), but I see nothing of that kind. If it really translates to a select for update, the database locks you. Do you need to lock across different VMs, or just within one VM? In the latter case you might try some Java synchronization mechanism instead.